# Eclipse throwing "Unresolved inclusion error" on standard includes like "stdio.h"

Tags: c, windows, header, eclipse-cdt, libraries

After installing Eclipse freshly on Windows 10, I imported code to work on, but Eclipse started throwing the error "Unresolved inclusion error" on standard libraries like `stdio.h` and `stdint.h`. Does Eclipse not install standard libraries or a compiler?

Comment: Eclipse is an generic IDE for a multitude of languages and more, and as such does not include any compiler, for no language. Many other IDEs follow the same pattern, and I would not be happy if an IDE includes a compiler of a specific language.

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to missing includes in general. It seems like Eclipse does not install a standard compiler for C/C++.

**The issue was resolved with the following steps:**

1. Installing MinGW
2. Adding the gcc and g++ to the PATH variable. Both of them were included in `C:\MinGW\bin`, since I did not change the installation path.
3. I included all includes and header file paths of the project into `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Cross GCC Compiler -> Includes`.
4. In the same include settings, I also added `C:\MinGW\include`, since thats the location of the standard include files for C/C++.
5. Rebuilding the index with `Project -> C/C++ Index -> Rebuild`.

If the options described above with the `Project` menu are not available, make sure the project you're referring to is marked in the project explorer of Eclipse.

Comment: Similarly, you'll have to add paths to any sub directory used in the application source. Eclipse linking/paths are very cumbersome to work with in general.

Comment: Yes thank you for that information, I missed to add that.